# Сокращенная функция Гаусса

Tags: графика, фильтры, распознавание-образов

В некоторых реализациях оператора Canny используются вместо обычной двумерной функции Гаусса вот такая двумерная функция:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть получается, от функции Гаусса берется только ее часть c экспонентой. 
Также в оригинальной рукописи Canny использовалась именно такая функция, но в интернете есть достаточно много реализаций и статей(в том числе на Хабре и в хороших книгах) с полной функцией.

**Вопрос**: какую функцию будет правильным использовать и в чем, собственно, разница между их использованием?

P.S.
Заметил, что при использовании обычной функции Гаусса, изображение магнитуды градиента вектора сильно затемняется и контуры почти не выделяются. А при другой все нормально.

Comment: Ничего не понял, но поставлю плюс ))

Comment: Можете уточнить подробности вопроса? Какого ответа вы хотите? Какой язык программирования?

Comment: @Suvitruf , язык программирование не имеет значения. Какого ответа я хочу? Хотел бы узнать, что творится(в хорошем смысле) в головах людей, которые используют стандартную двумерную функцию Гаусса вместо той, которая на картинке в алгоритме Оператора Canny.

А то, право, я теряюсь: на одних авторитетных источниках используется одна функция, на весьма немногочисленных других и в оригинальной рукописи - другая.

Comment: Ответ был найден:

"Canny operator looks for the point of maximum derivative and therefore the scale of the input function doesn't matter.

"Only the exponent part" seems to mean that just omitting the normalization factor. A convolution with the un-scaled gaussian will simply be proportional to the convolution with a normalized gaussian.

This should make no difference if the next operation is a maximum-derivative search."

Comment: Разница будет в математической точности, что может привести к изменению градиента в отрисовке, как вы и написали. Вы бы не задавали бы этого вопроса, если бы поняли как это функция работает с математического подхода, и тогда применили её правильно. Кстати там будут очень маленькая разница в значений.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант, который Вы привели, это двумерная функция распределения Гаусса
[image: Двумерная функция распределения Гаусса],

для которой принято, что функции распределения по x и по y равны, а интеграл функции равен 1. То есть коэффициент распределения σx = σy и нормализован относительно `1/sqrt(2*pi)`.